# Google Map geocoder returns multiple results against a complete town name (with county, state)

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have the following address:

"Chelsea, New York, NY, USA"

In the above address:

City = 'Chelsea'
County = "New York"
State = "NY"
Country = "USA"

When i pass this address to the Google's Geocoder API it returns multiple results, while i am expecting a single result because every part (name, county, state, country) of the town name is specified in the address.

Here is the code snippet:

(Assuming required files are already included)

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ "address": "Chelsea, New York, NY, USA" }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results.length == 1) {                       
                      // do something
                        }
                      else{
                         // do something
                        }
```

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The geocoder finds 2 matches to the string "Chelsea, New York, NY, USA"

```
[ 0 ]: Chelsea, New York, NY, USA (40.7497717, -73.99769459999999)
[ 1 ]: Travis - Chelsea, Staten Island, NY, USA (40.5890113, -74.19151769999996)
```

Your assumption that you will get "a single result because every part (name, county, state, country) of the town name is specified in the address" is not valid.

The first:

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "Chelsea",
      "short_name": "Chelsea",
      "types": [
        "neighborhood",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Manhattan",
      "short_name": "Manhattan",
      "types": [
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "Chelsea, New York, NY, USA",
  "geometry": {
    "bounds": {
      "ea": {
        "d": 40.7373582,
        "b": 40.7570384
      },
      "fa": {
        "b": -74.00886300000002,
        "d": -73.98779150000001
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "nb": 40.7497717,
      "ob": -73.99769459999999
    },
    "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
    "viewport": {
      "ea": {
        "d": 40.7373582,
        "b": 40.7570384
      },
      "fa": {
        "b": -74.00886300000002,
        "d": -73.98779150000001
      }
    }
  },
  "types": [
    "neighborhood",
    "political"
  ]
}
```

The second:

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "Travis - Chelsea",
      "short_name": "Travis - Chelsea",
      "types": [
        "neighborhood",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Staten Island",
      "short_name": "Staten Island",
      "types": [
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Richmond",
      "short_name": "Richmond",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "Travis - Chelsea, Staten Island, NY, USA",
  "geometry": {
    "bounds": {
      "ea": {
        "d": 40.57709699999999,
        "b": 40.603491
      },
      "fa": {
        "b": -74.20663830000001,
        "d": -74.17552469999998
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "nb": 40.5890113,
      "ob": -74.19151769999996
    },
    "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
    "viewport": {
      "ea": {
        "d": 40.57709699999999,
        "b": 40.603491
      },
      "fa": {
        "b": -74.20663830000001,
        "d": -74.17552469999998
      }
    }
  },
  "types": [
    "neighborhood",
    "political"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can u explain why my assumption is not valid.

Comment: Because the geocoder returns two results that match your input string "Chelsea, New York, NY, USA", one of which is in Richmond county, New York state, so it doesn't enforce any ordering on the input (and I wouldn't expect it to).

Comment: FYI, I would drop county since 'county' is not part of a postal address.